# D-peak of Raman Spectra of Graphite explanation

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, phonons, graphene, raman-spectroscopy

The D peak in the Raman Spectrum of Graphite is attributed to the breathing mode of $A_{1g)$ symmetry involving phonons near zone boundary. The explanation is the following:

The change of bond polarization with bond length is by
far the dominant term in the Raman matrix element for p
states. This term is large for the breathing mode of sixfold
rings. By symmetry, for a breathing mode of a graphite
plane, the contributions from each ring add constructively
because of the long-range polarization.

I don't quite understand this explanation: How do I visualize this and why is the change of bond polarization the dominant term. Also why does the Breathing mode have the maximum change? Any clarifications will be appreciated, thanks!